# Autocomplete Nodejs Not Working In VScode

Tags: node.js, npm, visual-studio-code

It is about `VS Code` problems. I am beginning to learn `NodeJS` on Youtube. I saw that, when they typed `validator`, `VS Code` with autocomplete all `validators` is available but me.

[image]